# Replacing single quote in python

Tags: python, json, replace

This is my json file

lines = """{
"Name": "Jennifer Smith",
"Contact Number": "7867567898",
"Email": "jen123@gmail.com",
"city": "EL FAR D'EMPORD\u00c0"
}"""

```
data =json.loads("[" + lines.replace("}{", "},\n{") + "]")
    for i in data:
        try:
            v_alertStatus = i['Name']
            print(v_alertStatus)
           # v_alertStatus = rep(v_alertStatus)
        except KeyError:
            v_alertStatus = ''
        try:
            v_severity = i['Contact Number']
            print(v_severity)
            #v_severity = rep(v_severity)
        except KeyError:
            v_severity = ''
        try:
            v_city = i['Email']
            print(v_city)
           # v_city = rep(v_city)
        except KeyError:
            v_city = ''
        try:
            v_eventAuthority = i['city']
            (v_eventAuthority).replace("'","\\'")
            print(v_eventAuthority)
            #v_eventAuthority = rep(v_eventAuthority)
        except KeyError:
            v_eventAuthority = ''
```

Im basically trying to replace "city": "EL FAR D'EMPORD\u00c0" -> "city": "EL FAR D'EMPORD\u00c0"

But my replace is not working
if i put ' -> it only takes '
if I put \' -> it gives me \'

How do I replace it with just one '? or odd number of backslashes?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question but you need a backslash for each character you want to escape. So if you wanted to replace a single quote with two backslashes, you need four backslashes.

Comment: I want to replace a single quote with either one or odd number of backslashes. Is it possible?

Comment: If you want to replace with a backslash you need an extra backslash to escape your first backslash. So you need two for one

Answer (score 0):

Python's `replace` method is not in place, meaning you need to assign the result to a variable. See this modified code which gives the correct output.

```
import json

lines = """{ "Name": "Jennifer Smith", "Contact Number": "7867567898", "Email": "jen123@gmail.com", "city": "EL FAR D'EMPORD\u00c0" }"""
data =json.loads("[" + lines.replace("}{", "},\n{") + "]")
for i in data:
    try:
        v_alertStatus = i['Name']
        print(v_alertStatus)
        # v_alertStatus = rep(v_alertStatus)
    except KeyError:
        v_alertStatus = ''
    try:
        v_severity = i['Contact Number']
        print(v_severity)
        #v_severity = rep(v_severity)
    except KeyError:
        v_severity = ''
    try:
        v_city = i['Email']
        print(v_city)
        # v_city = rep(v_city)
    except KeyError:
        v_city = ''
    try:
        v_eventAuthority = i['city']
        v_eventAuthority = v_eventAuthority.replace("\'","\\'")
        print(v_eventAuthority)
        #v_eventAuthority = rep(v_eventAuthority)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Output:

```
Jennifer Smith
7867567898
jen123@gmail.com
EL FAR D\'EMPORDÀ
```